# How to make INPUT element fill the entire table TD cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With this example table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <input value = "this is the text">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the `<input>` element populating the table's `<td>` cell. By default it (the `<input>` element) does not take all the space available by its `<td>` cell. How to make sure that the `<input>` element always fills the space from edge to edge?

[image]

Comment: What CSS styling have you applied to it?

Comment: Let's assume there was no CSS style assigned to those elements yet....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table td input {
  // display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <input value = "this is the text">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using <input type="text">:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box /* Just in case if you have defined
                           left or right padding to the input */
}
```

Comment: (Years later): Does this (still) work? W3schools says this about the width parameter of an input: "The input height and width attributes specify the height and width of an <input type="image"> element.". About the size parameter it says: "Note: The size attribute works with the following input types: text, search, tel, url, email, and password.". Admittedly the size works in characters and the width is table relative. But the code wrangling I was doing showed width to be ignored for my text field.